# How to upload files to AWS S3 from NestJS ( Suggestion )

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, nestjs

im working in my reutilizable code, and i have for you
a FileService to Upload files to AWS S3 with NestJS.

The if conditional that you see in the code about cloudPlatform variable
is because this is not the final code.

Eventually this service will be able to upload to many cloud platforms like
GCP, Azure, AWS and FileSystem.

```
import { Injectable, Logger, NotFoundException, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { IAWS_S3 } from './interfaces/aws-s3.interface';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class FileService {


    /**
     * 
     * @variable cloudPlatform is the tecnology to save files in the cloud
     * @variable awsConfig is the Amazon Web Service S3 configuration
     * @S3 is the S3 to instanciate your credentials to use Amazon Web Service
     */
    private logger = new Logger('FileService');
    private cloudPlatform: string = this.configService.get('uploadFilesSettings').fileUploadPlatform;
    private awsConfig: IAWS_S3;
    private s3: S3;
    
    constructor(
        private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    ) {
        if ( this.cloudPlatform === 'AWS_S3' ) {
            this.awsConfig = this.configService.get<IAWS_S3>('aws');
            this.s3 = new S3( this.awsConfig );
        }
    }

    /**
     * * Function to upload files sent from the body
     * @param files of the request body in an object 
     * @returns an object with properties that are an string array 
     *          like this obj = { prop1: ['a.jpg','b.jpg'], prop2: ['test.gif'] ...prop n }
     */
    async uploadFiles<T, U>( files: T ): Promise<U> {
        let props = Object.keys(files);
        let arrPromisesPending = await this.getArrayToUpload<T>( props, files );

        let arrPromisesDone = await Promise.all(
            arrPromisesPending.map( async( file: Express.Multer.File ) => {
                return {
                    fieldname: file.fieldname,
                    ...( await this.uploadFileTo( file, this.cloudPlatform )),
                }
            })
        )

        return await this.getUploadedFiles<U>( arrPromisesDone, props );
    }

    /**
     * * Function to get an array of objects of the files sent from the body
     * * to make a Promise.all() 
     * @param props all properties ( fieldname in the form-data body ) of the files object
     * @param files of the request body in an object 
     * @returns an array of objects that every object is the file that will be uploaded 
     */
    async getArrayToUpload<T>( props: string[], files: T ): Promise<Object[]> {
        let promises: Object[] = [];
        props.map(( prop: string ) => {

            files[prop].map(( file: Express.Multer.File ) =>  {

                promises.push( file );

            });
        })
        return promises;
    }

    /**
     * * Function that upload the file to cloud platform
     * @param file object to upload
     * @param cloudPlatform site where files will be uploaded
     * @returns the response of cloudPlatform
     */
    async uploadFileTo( file: Express.Multer.File, cloudPlatform: string ): Promise<any> {
        let type: string = file.originalname.split(".").pop();
        let genericFilename: string = `${ uuid() }-${ moment().format().split('T')[0] }`;

        if ( cloudPlatform === 'AWS_S3' ) {

            try {
                return await this.s3.upload({
                    Bucket: this.awsConfig.bucketName,
                    Key: `${ genericFilename }.${ type }`,
                    Body: file.buffer,
                    ContentType: file.mimetype,
                }).promise();

            } catch ( error ) { 
                this.logger.error( error );
                throw new InternalServerErrorException('Unexpected error, check server logs');
            }
            
        }
        
        this.logger.error('Set .env variable "FILE_UPLOAD_PLATFORM"');
        throw new InternalServerErrorException('Unexpected error, check server logs');
    }


    /**
     * * Function to format the names of the files uploaded to the cloud 
     * * platform and return them in an object with the corresponding
     * * properties and each of these will have an array of strings
     * 
     * @param arrPromisesDone an array of objects that were uploaded
     * @param props that's means fieldnames of the files
     * @returns 
     * ! Example of returns -----------------------------------------------------------
     * ! {
     * !     avatar: ['image1.png','image2.jpg', 'image3.jpeg', 'image4.jpg'],
     * !     background: ['image1.png','image2.jpg', 'image3.jpeg', 'image4.jpg'],
     * ! }
     */
    async getUploadedFiles<T>( arrPromisesDone: Object[], props: string[] ): Promise<T> {
        let uploadedFiles: any = {};
        props.map(( prop: string ) => {

            uploadedFiles[prop] = [];
            arrPromisesDone.map(( file: any ) =>  {

                if ( file.fieldname === prop ) {
                    uploadedFiles[prop].push( file.key );
                }

            });
        });
        return uploadedFiles;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param imageName name of the image
     * @param res @Res() to response from Express
     * @returns the image obtained from the cloud platform to client
     */
    async getFile( imageName: string, res: Response ) {
        const params = { Bucket: this.awsConfig.bucketName, Key: imageName };

        if ( this.cloudPlatform === 'AWS_S3' ) {

            try {
                const data = await this.s3.getObject( params ).promise();
                
                res.contentType( data.ContentType );
                return res.send( data.Body );
    
            } catch ( error ) {
                if ( error.statusCode === 404 ) 
                    throw new NotFoundException(`image ${ imageName } don't exist`);
                
                this.logger.error( error );
                throw new InternalServerErrorException('Unexpected error, check server logs');
            }
        }

        this.logger.error('Set .env variable "FILE_UPLOAD_PLATFORM"');
        throw new InternalServerErrorException('Unexpected error, check server logs');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: do it like you would do in plain nodejs. See this package: https://github.com/squareboat/nest-storage/